# Can I get List Sort Options on a 2sxc App?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have an App on 2sxc, I want to be able to order the items on my view.

The view shows a Category with X subcategories and on the Subcategories I have X Items.

I want to be able to Sort the Subcategories Order and the Items Order, I don't know how to do it.

I tried to add the option on the toolbar but as I expected I got an error:

> Had an error talking to the server (status 400).
> Message: The request is invalid.
> Detail: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'guid' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'ToSic.Sxc.WebApi.ItemLists.EntityInListDto Header(System.Guid)' in 'ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.WebApi.Cms.ContentGroupController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

I need to do this, and I don't know if I can do it only with 2sxc or if I need to use something else to do it.

Thanks.

UPDATE**
Thanks for your answers, finally I solved this changing how I treated the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maria, it sounds like you are just getting started and need to get more of the pieces and parts of 2sxc figured out before you can tackle this. The two main ways to approach this that come to mind are:

1. In C# and LINQ code in the View. Are you familiar with either of those? If not, then,
2. Using a Visual Query to list, modify, and sort the data before outputting it in the View. Given your description of the categories/subcategories, I am not sure, but there is a TreeView datasource that might be helpful.

If you are a beginner, both of the above are going to seem pretty advanced at first.

Also, I am confused by what you mean about, "I tried to add the option on the toolbar..." Could you show us how you did that? Was it in the View's Razor/C# template? If not, maybe a screenshot?

Another helpful thing is for us to know the versions of both DNN and 2sxc. Those are usually key to understanding errors and really helpful in what type of recommendations we can make.

Two things I can say for sure, a) DataTables.net is a great tool for presenting data when you need to have the info displayed in a grid (table) and get built-in useful column sorting and b) you can definitely do whatever you need with 2sxc. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the view use a Razor script?  If so, you should be able to use a Linq query tomordernthenlist based on the subcategory.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to order on code, I want to be able to order the items on the view, like we do it on the Content app with all list items. Someone recommended me to do something like https://datatables.net/ , I'll try it